# Laptop's Keyboard fell down when I cleaned the fan

Tags: keyboard, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

Now, 4, r, f, v keys are pairing with 9,o,l,. keys, like this: clicking 4, the output is 94. Clicking 94, the result is exactly the same, 94.
r is or, o is also or. f is lf, l is lf; v is.v, . is also .v
Can this be repaired? How can this be repaired?
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T61.

Answer (score 1):

To be 100% sure it is the laptop keyboard (and not the controller) that is the issue, plug in a USB keyboard into the laptop and test the keys on it.  If everything works fine on the USB keyboard, then it is definitely the laptop keyboard that is having the issue.

Unplug the laptop keyboard completely and inspect it for damage, such as cracks.  Also, check to see if there is any debris stuck to it and gently remove it.  Reattach the keyboard carefully, being sure to properly reconnect its cable.  Obviously, if there is physical damage, it will need to be replaced.  If there is debris that was removed, or perhaps the cable wasnt seated properly, hopefully the problem is resolved.

If not, you will have to get a replacement keyboard.  If it is under warranty, you might be able to get it replaced for free.  Generally speaking, replacement keyboards are not very expensive.  You should be able to find it on the Lenovo website, or just call their support to get a price.

Comment: I find the "Unplug the laptop keyboard" a bit too easily written. You do realize, you ask here to dismantle the laptop so the keyboard board can be inspected, right? This is a very tedious job that may go wrong if you don't know what you're doing. I would definitely suggest looking for a guide video on youtube on how to do it for his specific model or suggest a repairshop.

Comment: @LPChip he was already inside the laptop if he was cleaning the fan

Comment: You can actually clean the fan from the outside.